# Why does python regex seem to fail to match beyond 112 bytes?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file, **what.dmp**, which is 116 bytes long. And my python code looks like this:

```
import binascii
import re
import sys

print(sys.version)

needle = re.compile(b".{112}")

with open("what.dmp", "rb") as haystack:
  chunk = haystack.read()
  print("Read {0} bytes.".format(len(chunk)))
  matches = needle.search(chunk)
  if matches:
    print(matches.start())
    print(binascii.hexlify(matches.group(0)))
  else:
    print("No matches found.")
```

Running this code is fine:

```
C:\test>C:\Python33\python.exe test.py
3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
Read 116 bytes.
0
b'0101060001010600087e88758f4e8e75534589751df7897583548775e4bcf001e6d0f001cae3f001ccf7f0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090d91300000000002c003100eb6fb024'
```

However, change the regex from 112 to 113:

```
needle = re.compile(b".{113}")
```

And no match is found:

```
C:\test>C:\Python33\python.exe test.py
3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
Read 116 bytes.
No matches found.
```

So the question is: why does the regex not match the 113th character. I haven't posted what.dmp because surely the contents are irrelevant?!

Many thanks!

Comment: There is a very good chance that byte 113 is equivalent to `\n`, (10 in binary, 0a in hex).  Try adding the `re.DOTALL` flag to your regex.

Comment: Argh! It is! It's 0x0A. And so the RegEx is only evaluating the line. I thought using the 'b' prefix would say these are bytes. I'm guessing there's a switch to solve this..?

Comment: if you are dealing with binary data, use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module instead of regular expressions.

Comment: @F.J re.DOTALL solved it. Anyway of giving you the credit even though you've commented rather than answered?

Comment: @PauloScardine I'm just searching a binary file for some binary bytes to see if they exist - I'm not extracting a data structure. So I _think_ I've no need for struct..?

Comment: no need for regular expressions then, just use `if needle in haystack: print("Gotcha!)"`.

Comment: @Bridgey Added the suggestion as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good chance that byte 113 is equivalent to `\n`, (10 in binary, 0a in hex). Try adding the re.DOTALL flag to your regex.

However as noted in comments, you probably don't need regular expressions for this.